# javascript get selected value from form (in Netbeans web project with DB)

Tags: javascript, database, netbeans, javabeans, netbeans-7

I need little help.
First, I have page with some values from Database in form, like this:

```
out.println("<form method=\"post\" action=\"update.jsp?id=" + 
                    rs.getString(1) +"\" onSubmit=\"return editF(this)\" id=\"editDiv"+ rs.getString(1) +"\" >" + SelectCat() +" </form>")
public String SelectCat()
    {
        String result = "<select name=\"category\" >";
        try
        {
            String request = "SELECT * FROM cat";
            Statement st = getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(request);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                result += "<option value=\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\">" + rs.getString(2) + "</option>";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        result += "</select>";
        return result;
    }
```

And my javascript function is

```
 function editF(form)
{
    alert("a");
    string header = form.header.value;
    string text = form.text.value;
    string category = form.category.selectedIndex.value;
    var e = document.getElementByName("category");
    //var category = e.selectedIndex;
    form.action = form.action + "&header="+header+"&text="+text+"&categoryID="+category;
    return true;
};
```

But I can't get selected value.
Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var category = form.category.options[ form.category.selectedIndex ].value;
```

Also, javascript is not a strongly-typed language, you cannot define its type when declaring it. Instead, use `var`.

Comment: I took the line from his javascript part and made it so that it could work.

Comment: I need to take out this `string` though.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me!
And yes, I was confused about 'string' and 'var'. :)

Comment: Check the "v" on the left my answer then, it will check this answer as "best answer". See here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work